# Using mongodb to store a single but complex JSON object

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I want to store a single, big and complex JSON object in mongodb and I want to be able to retrieve and modify specific parts of it. A simple solution would be to store it in a single document, but I'm not sure how that would play with multiple write requests. Another option would be to keep every node of the JSON in different documents, kind of like a pattern explained [here in the mongodb documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-ancestors-array/). This way I can retrieve only parts of the whole object and work on them that way.

My question is: do I get anything out of the latter approach? I'm kind of new to mongodb, but as I read it has [database lock](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/) on multiple write requests, so it would seem that having my JSON taken apart like this would achieve nothing when it comes to scaling.

Comment: So much depends on the details - how big is big? number of fields, number of sub-documents, overall size in bytes, etc. How many documents overall? How frequently are you inserting? Updating? Querying?

Comment: Some background: we started out building a REST API that saves to a JavaScript object, with an automatic mapping between endpoints and nodes of the object. This object is now stored in memory as a JavaScript variable periodically saved to a file, but we want to have some other type of persistence. so these parameters are pretty much undetermined, we want to switch to saving the data in mongo db because the previous method is not scalable.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider to store data larger then 16MB you should definitely use some sort of hashing as mongodb has a 16MB size limit on its documents.

From [MongoDB Limits and Thresholds](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/)

> The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes.